# How to save settings made in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Is there any way I can save changes made by a user , so that at the next run they would still be there? I have seen something about My.Settings , is that how it is done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you have multiple options, you can create a file and load it on startup, or you can use the built in settings object. Just go to your `Project Property's` --> `settings` set your variable there, the you can access it through `My.Settings`

[image]

Then load it like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim greeting As String = My.Settings.mySetting
End Sub
```

you would change the value and save it like this

```
My.Settings.mySetting = "GoodBye"
My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: Thank you! Works as expected. Here is something that may help some, add a control "Checkbox" to your form and use this

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then
My.Settings.Username = txtuname.Text
 My.Settings.Password = txtpass.Text
My.Settings.Save()
Else
My.Settings.Reset()
End If
```