# How to have application's Contextmenu user settings remembered when opened next time?

Tags: vb.net, contextmenustrip

Using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I've added a contextmenustrip with four options - options A, B, C and D on my form. I've written these in such a way that only one remains checked at a given time. It works fine while using. But I would like to know how to save these settings (if changed) and restore when the application is opened next time.

This is my code so far:

```
    Private Sub OptionA_ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles OptionA_ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    OptionA_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = True
    OptionB_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
    OptionC_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
    OptionD_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionB_ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles OptionB_ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    OptionB_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = True
    OptionA_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
    OptionC_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
    OptionD_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionC_ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles OptionC_ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    OptionC_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = True
    OptionA_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
    OptionB_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
    OptionD_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionD_ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles OptionD_ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    OptionD_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = True
    OptionC_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
    OptionA_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
    OptionB_ToolStripMenuItem1.Checked = False
End Sub
```

Thanks in adv!

Comment: this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351800/how-to-save-settings-made-in-vb

Comment: Thanks DeanOC! I was looking for a setting dealt with Boolean types. However this did help! Thx again!