# how to save printer name configuration to string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

how to select and save the printer name configuration to a string. If I reopen then automatically the name of the printer I selected earlier it appears on the form.

Thanks

```
 Private Sub configurationfile()
        Dim reader As New System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader
        Dim PrinterName As String = reader.GetValue("PrinterName", GetType(String)).ToString().Replace(",", "")

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(PrinterName) Then
            TextBox1.Text = PrinterName
            CheckBox1.Checked = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        Dim fullpath = Application.StartupPath + "\rawprinting.exe"
        Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(fullpath)
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("PrinterName")
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("PrinterName", TextBox1.Text)
        Else
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("PrinterName", "")
        End If

        'Save the changes in App.config file.
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
    End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 Dim printer As String = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PrinterName" value="Generic / Text Only" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's 2022... why are you using Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Dai , from the code that posts it may not matter if I use vs2010

Comment: Project > Properties > Settings, press F1 to get help.

Comment: @HansPassant , I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @user19541848 You can use the application settings as somewhere to save the string. If you click on the "Project" menu, then choose the "<your project name> Properties..." item, click on the "Settings" item on the left, and then press F1, it will take you to a help page which can be a starting point for learning how to use the application settings.

Comment: @AndrewMorton , I created a config but open or start the application is not the name of the printer in the textbox and I've updated the code in the post

Comment: @user19541848 It looks like you're doing it the difficult way. Does [How to save settings made in VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351800/how-to-save-settings-made-in-vb) help? (N.B. You should never try to write to the directory that the program is in: for most users that should be a read-only location for security against malware.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference link below I answered the answer
Here's [a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.appsettingsreader?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)!

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub configurationfile()
        Dim reader As New System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader
        Dim sourceFolder As String = reader.GetValue("Printer Name", GetType(String)).ToString().Replace(",", "")

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceFolder) Then
            TextBox1.Text = sourceFolder
            CheckBox1.Checked = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        Dim fullpath = Application.StartupPath + "\WindowsApplication3.exe"
        Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(fullpath)
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("Printer Name")
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Printer Name", TextBox1.Text)
        Else
            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Printer Name", "")
        End If

        'Save the changes in App.config file.
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Using sprinters As New PrintDialog
            sprinters.ShowNetwork = True
            If sprinters.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim PrintSettings As PrinterSettings = sprinters.PrinterSettings
                sb.Append(sprinters.PrinterSettings.PrinterName & vbNewLine)
                TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString & vbNewLine
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        configurationfile()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community , 
I have provided the link information of my answer